# delete anything before and after a specific tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

I only want the `<table>` without the first `<tr>` and remove anything before and after `<table>`.

```
<div id=aaa>
<div>
<table>
<tr><td>text one</td></tr>
<tr><td>text two</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
more text
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code that you are struggling with so far?

Comment: Does this mean you want to replace the whole `body` with only the table? Or what does "everything before and after" mean? HTML documents are hierarchical.

Comment: @FelixKling - Dude said everything? `document.write('<table><tr><td>text two</td></tr></table>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('table tr').not(':nth-child(2)').remove() //remove everything but second
$('#aaa').html($('table')); //replace the outer element with this node
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gr87R/2/)

Comment: second child, not first child.